# Выбор диапазона данных в MySQL + PHP

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Здравствуйте.
Я таким вот образом генерирую ссылки:

```
function links()
{
$qname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM note");
$qnum = mysql_num_rows($qname);
for ($i = 1; $i < $qnum / 10 + 1; $i++)
{
    echo "<div class='links'>"."<a href='/guestbook/guestbook.php?id=".$i."'>".$i."</a>"."</div>";
}
```

}

При нажатии на ссылку "1" должны отобразиться первые 10 записей, "2" - 11-20 и тд.
Такой вопрос:
как в запросе вида

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM note WHERE id LIKE ' ' ");
id - первичный ключ auto_increment
```

указать диапазон, который менялся бы в зависимости от передаваемого id?

Comment: Все, разобрался. все просто. я тупой.
    mysql_query("SELECT id, name, message, date FROM note WHERE id > '".$_GET['id']."0' ")

Comment: В SQL есть парочка вариантов. В зависимости от требований и извращенного мнения программиста.
SELECT * FROM `note` LIMIT 1,10;
SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE `id` BETWEEN 1 and 10;

Надеюсь, что вы понимаете, что ваш код очень подвержен SQL-Injection!

Comment: Стыдно признаваться, но я не знаю что такое sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде так

```sql
SELECT * FROM `note` WHERE 'id'>10 LIMIT 1,10
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну так вот про SQL-Injection посмотрите тут: [внедрение SQL-кода](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0).

Насколько я понимаю, вы мучаетесь с по страничкой. Вам для выбора диапазона также надо будет сделать запрос на полное количество элементов отвечающих запросу:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT что FROM где WHERE условия");
$numRows=mysql_num_rows($q);*
```

После чего будете делать уже непосредственно запрос для выбора элементов либо в цикле извлекать из уже ранее сделанного запроса (учтите, при малом количестве записей это еще куда ни шло, но потом будет ...)

Можно сделать так:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS,
```

еще что-то FROM где WHERE условие LIMIT с записи, сколько записей.

Результат - необходимая выборка. Для по странички нужно знать общее количество записей (то есть кол. стр = общее кол. записей / кол. элементов на стр.)

Его найти очень легко выполнив тут же:

```sql
SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS total
```

Совет: **не изобретайте очередной велик!** Поищите постраничный модуль! Там же будут примеры применения!